# Is there any way to apply z-index to an image in python-docx word report or some other way to add a background/watermark image in python-docx report?

Tags: python, odoo, python-docx, odoo-12

I am trying to create a word document report in Odoo 12 with the help of the python-docx. I have come across a problem where I want to add a watermark or background image in the document but it seems like there's no possible way to do it. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some example code.

Comment: you can use add_picture function of docx object. I am sure you can give with width. @Dodge

Comment: Yeah width is fine but what I want is add a whole image in the background but using the add_picture method with the width doesn't make the picture as the background instead it acts as normal content of the page.